# Toolbar goes mysteriously grey when VStack background color is set

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have (reproducible, just put in xcode)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("hi")
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(Color.gray)
    .border(.red)
    .toolbar {
        // items
    }
}
```

For some reason the toolbar goes grey as well. Why? The border clearly shows that the VStack doesn't extend to behind the toolbar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjLxV.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("hi")
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background {
      Color.gray
    }
    .border(.red)
    .toolbar {
        // items
    }
}
```